# How to show the default list view configuration option in lightning:listView

Tags: lightning, list-view

I am new to Salesforce and I am trying to customize the lightning:listView, it shows the gear icon but when I open that it only shows the heading of 'List view control' unlike in default list view where there are many configuration options such as New, Clone, Rename, etc. What should I do to make this lightning:listView look exactly like the default list view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:listView/documentation),

lightning:listView supports the following features:

- Inline editing
- Mass inline editing for single record types
- Resizing and sorting of columns
- Search
- Text wrapping
- Loading of additional rows

> You can configure inline editing. Other features aren't configurable.
>   Additionally, the following features are not supported via the
>   lightning:listView UI.

- Creating or deleting of list views
- Modifying of the list view filter
- Switching to other list views

In order to create, clone or rename you have to rely on standard List view or you can try writing your own custom component(a complex solution as per me).